# How to add submodules within submodules

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I want to have submodules within my submodule. Adding the sub-submodule throws an error

```
(Parent)
|
 --submodule--(Editor)
|
 --submodule--(Editor)/(AndroidEditor)
```

I add them with commands:

```
git submodule add https://xx.git submodules/Editor/
git submodule add -f https://yy.git submodules/Editor/AndroidEditor
```

And get the error adding the second submodule:

> fatal: Pathspec 'submodules/Editor/AndroidEditor' is in submodule
>   'submodules/Editor' Failed to add submodule
>   'submodules/Editor/AndroidEditor'

Is the only way to add the sub-submodule from adding it to the **Editor** git repo and not to the **Parent** ?

Comment: Yes. A sub-submodule has to be a submodule of a submodule, it cannot be a sub-submodule of a superproject.

Comment: Did you try to go into the "Editor" directory and run the command: "run git submodule add https://yy.git"? In this way it should create the .gitmodule file with "AndroidEditor" module description inside.